# Python local install python package fails because "account does not have write access"

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, powershell, windows-terminal

I've been using python for a while on my unix based machine, but I'm trying to use a windows machine now to install locally some of the packages I made.

What I normally do in unix navigate to the folder with setup.py and run the following command in terminal

```
python -m pip install -e .
```

On my windows machine I installed [Windows Terminal](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/windows-terminal/9n0dx20hk701?activetab=pivot:overviewtab), which uses powershell. Trying the same thing I get:

```
C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-bohtedqu\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\install.py:34: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: setup.py install is deprecated. Use build and pip and other standards-based tools.
      warnings.warn(
    error: cant create or remove files in install directory

Perhaps your account does not have write access to this directory?  If the
installation directory is a system-owned directory, you may need to sign in
as the administrator or "root" account.  If you do not have administrative
access to this machine, you may wish to choose a different installation
directory, preferably one that is listed in your PYTHONPATH environment
variable.
```

I've looked up how to fix this and nothing has worked. I've tried starting Windows Terminal as an administrator, get the same thing. I've also tried downloading [gsudo](https://github.com/gerardog/gsudo) and adding sudo to the start of my command, nothing changes. I'm really not that familiar with python on windows so I might be doing something incredibly dumb, any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Run cmd as administrator and activate super administrator as 'net user administrator /active:yes'. Restart your system as super administrator .Hope that will solve problem.

Comment: Nope, causes the same error unfortunately. Pretty crazy that "super administrator" is not enough permission.

Comment: Then all you need to do is to navigate to that folder and run 'python setup.py install' using cmd

Comment: Make sure you have latest version of pip installed.

Comment: unfortunately, still gives the same error.

Comment: Can you share  code sandbox link

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "code sandbox link." Are you asking me to share the module I am trying to install? Unfortunately, I don't want to share this project publicly